# Splash screen generated but not appearing in Ionic 2

Tags: xml, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen

I am using Ionic 2 and have generated splash and icons through command line.
But the **splash** and the **icon** are not showing in the app.

There might be a problem regarding the version, or config or something else.
It will be very helpful if some could help me.

Thank you

Here is my config.xml


    Valquik
    Valet service
    Valquik Team

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<splash src="splash.png" />

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>    
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
</platform>

<preference name="permissions" value="internet"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0xFFFFFFFF"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
</feature>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0"/>
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
<icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include these preference and see if it works:

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
```

Comment: Black screen and default cordova app icon are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077) in cordova-android platform version 6.0.0 which copies the resources to /res instead of /platforms/android/res. The latest version of cordova (6.5.0) has cordova-android platform version 6.1.1 which fixes this bug.

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

It might be necessary to manually update the cordova-android version too.

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the White SplashScreen problem. With the last version of Ionic, you need to verify a line in your config.xml file :

Make sure you have the line :
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>`

Instead of this wrong one :
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>`

You need to have the value "screen" here and not the old version which is "splash" !!!

Now my SplashScreen is not white anymore and it takes my resources files generated from PSD file.

And here is my Ionic Info prompt :

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```